# How to enable Javascript Webview or WKWebview in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I develop a mobile application and my application have to connect a website. I try make a webview and Wkwebview but I didn't get any result.
Website have 3 textbox and Javascript func control this textbox. If textbox text is not valid, textbox border is red when click the button. But my webview doesn't display all of this function I wrote lots of codes like it but it didn't work.

```
var config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        config.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds , configuration: config)
        self.view = self.webView
        self.modelPaymentResult.paymentResultDelegate = self
        self.indicatorShow(status: true)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let url = URL (string: "http://***************************")
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(requestObj)
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        self.navigationItem.title = "Güvenli Ödeme"


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

 let javaScriptString = "validateinput()"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString, completionHandler: nil)
}
```